# Core Data ANY BETWEEN predicate

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I'm trying to create an NSPredicate to find 'projects' that contain 'sessions' within a certain date range. I tried this at first:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY sessions.date BETWEEN {$STARTDATE, $ENDDATE}"];
```

But I get an exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
   'to-many key not allowed here'
```

It seems BETWEEN does not work with ANY in this way. I'm also limited in use of () and AND clauses meaning I can't use something like:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY (sessions.date > $STARTDATE && sessions.date < $ENDDATE)"];
```

If I try that I get a parse error. And of course sessions.date is really a set so ANDing it like that doesn't really make a lot of sense.

How can I do this?

Thanks

UPDATE: Note that this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY sessions.date > $STARTDATE && ANY sessions.date < $ENDDATE"];
```

Is incorrect because it returns a project where there is a session greater than the start date and another session less than the end date but no session in between.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a case where you need a [`SUBQUERY`](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/Reference/NSExpression.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSExpression/expressionForSubquery:usingIteratorVariable:predicate:) expression:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(sessions, $s, $s.date BETWEEN {$STARTDATE, $ENDDATE}).@count > 0"];
```

Comment: The SUBQUERY stuff is a little buried in the NSExpression documentation and doesn't get much treatment in the Core Data-specific guides. Definitely file an enhancement request and let the Apple folks know where you would have looked for it (but didn't find the information you needed).